# IF cells in column A contains a dates that are 7 days before today's date then output the date and the value in the column next to it in a list

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a vehicle compliance sheet:

- Column A contains dates of next vehicle inspection.
- Column B contains vehicle registration numbers.

I am looking for a formula that will look up dates in column A that are 7 days prior to today's date and then output a list of these dates and the corresponding vehicle reg in column B.

When returning the values, I would like this list also to be in date order from nearest date to today and so forth.

Thanks so much in advance for any help.

I have tried multiple formula but can't seem to get it right. I have basic excel understanding but this has been a problem.

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly, from the explanation posted in the OP, then one could use the following formula,

[image]

---

• Formula used in cell <kbd>D2</kbd>

```
=SORT(FILTER(RegTable,RegTable[Date]>=TODAY()-7))
```

---

Or,

```
=SORT(FILTER(RegTable,(RegTable[Date]>=TODAY()-7)*(RegTable[Date]<TODAY())))
```

---

**Note:** In the given screenshot, using sample data, also converted the source into `Structured References` aka `Tables`, so it helps to automatically expand the formula when new data is added. Functions used works with `Excel 2021/MS365` onwards.

---